# Extracting parts of text string between two characters

Tags: r, regex

I am new to **R** and still learning so I would appreciate so much any help or suggestion.

I have different character strings similar to those:

```
"Department of Biophysical Chemistry, University of Braunschweig, Braunschweig, Germany; Consejo Superior de Investigaciones Científicas, CCHS, Madrid, Spain;"
```

Then I would like to extract only the name of the countries in those strings, including semicolon, that is:

```
"Germany; Spain;"
```

The problem for me is finding out how to extract just from the last coma to the semicolon and do that repeatedly. I tried with gsub function but I was not able to make the right approach..

Comment: This is can be easily achieved with regex, but if you interested only in country names or a specific type of information, you should leverage `NER`.

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `strsplit` along with `sub` here for a base R option:

```
x <- "Department of Biophysical Chemistry, University of Braunschweig, Braunschweig, Germany; Consejo Superior de Investigaciones Científicas, CCHS, Madrid, Spain;"
terms <- sapply(strsplit(x, ";\\s*")[[1]], function(x) {
    sub("^.*\\s+", "", x)
})
output <- paste0(terms, ";", collapse=" ")
output

[1] "Germany; Spain;"
```

The logic here is to first split your semicolon-separated string on the pattern `;\s*`, which results in a list containing each department.  Then, we use `apply` to remove everything up to, and including, the last appearance of whitespace.  Finally we paste collapse to generate another semicolon separated string.

Note: I changed the names of the output vector only for demo purposes, because R was using the full department description as the name by default, making it hard to display.

Answer (score 1):

For test input make a 3 component vector `s` as shown in the Note at the end so that we can see that it works for multiple lines -- here just three lines.

Now, we can get a one-line solution using `strapply` in the gsubfn package. We match the indicated pattern returning only the match to the capture group, i.e. the portion within parentheses.  Then for each line we use `sapply` to `paste` the matches together.

```
library(gsubfn)

sapply(strapply(s, ", ([^,;]+;)"), paste, collapse = " ")
```

giving:

```
[1] "Germany; Spain;" "Germany; Spain;" "Germany; Spain;"
```

### Note

```
s1 <- "Department of Biophysical Chemistry, University of Braunschweig, Braunschweig, Germany; Consejo Superior de Investigaciones Científicas, CCHS, Madrid, Spain;"
s <- c(s1, s1, s1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply find the last comma before the `;` and capture everything between using a simple `gsub` call. This will also work for a vector

```
gsub(".*?(=?[^,]*;)", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] " Germany; Spain;"
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and time! Regarding the abovementioned proposals I still have a minor question. In some cases like "United States", "Russian Federation" or similar, only the last term of country names are given, namely: "States", "Federation". How can I get the whole name of countries with multiple terms? Thanks again and sorry for possible inconveniences.

Comment: Just remove the space from the expression. e.g., `gsub(".*?(=?[^,]*;)", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)`. Though that will create an extra space at the beginning.